# Enable dead key diacritic indicator

Tags: keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I recently tried Debian Buster with KDE Plasma 5 and I noticed a cool feature which I'd like to have on my current distribution.

I use a US international keyboard with dead keys layout and, with Debian, as soon as I press a dead key (such as ` or '):

> the diacritic is displayed, along with an indication that the system is waiting for another keystroke to complete the typing sequence.

(to quote [Wikipedia's Dead key page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key#Usage))

I took a screen recording to let you better understand what I'm talking about:

[image]

Do you know if this is an exclusively Debian feature?
Is there any way I can have it on any other GNU+Linux distribution?

Comment: If you save your screen recording as an animated GIF, you can embed it directly in your question.